# How to use Futures for Multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrent.futures

I am new to Scala. I am learning multi-threading in Scala. One way of Multi-threading in Scala is `scala.actors` but it is deprecated nowadays. So the new way is to use `scala.concurrent` or `akka.actor`. I want to use `scala.concurrent`.
Scenario:
I want to make a chat server which accepts connections of multiple clients simultaneously and responses back.
the way I am trying to do is:

```
    while(true) {
      socket = serverSocket.accept()
      os = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream)
      br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))

      val newClient = Future {
        os.println("\n\nPlease Enter the Table name to be Extracted\t:")
        restr = br.readLine()

        println("data received from ["+socket.getInetAddress()+"] ["+socket.getPort()+"] and TableName ["+ restr +"]\n")
        new Extractor().extract(dbURL,userId,password,restr,os)
      }
     val clientFormed= newClient.isCompleted
      println("New Client Connection ? ["+clientFormed+"]")
    }
```

but after running the program The output says:

```
New Response made [false]
```

Means the Futures didn't Execute. Even the sleep is not working.
I know I am lacking something here but can't figure it out.

**UPDATE**
I know while(true) inside future is not the Correct way but while true is necessary for continuous run of server. I know my way is wrong. What I'm asking is: what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

`response` is a future starting with a `while(true)`. There is no way it can ever complete.

Comment: So what else should I use or do??

Comment: @YashBhardwaj Do you understand what a `Future` is? It's like a box that will hold the result of some computation that will be completed at some point in the future. In your code, the computation contains an infinite loop, so the computation will never be done. Remove the loop, and the whole `serverSocket.accept()` part out of the `Future`. There's too much to explain in a comment here.

Comment: @Jesper okay that's right. I think I misunderstood Future. Sorry for that. The all I want to do is make a multithreaded server like a chat room. I saw [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dX_pgQuEB2o#t=24.868041) video which is using `scala.actors` but that is deprecated. Future is the new concept for concurrecy (I believe). So that is the thing.